# Export MySQL table into a CSV file in specified folder ( which makes it dynamic )

Tags: mysql

I want to export all my data from a table to a csv file in the same folder my website is at.

```
mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT *
FROM grades
INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
```

There is no problem when it creates the file, but it saves it at the data location of MySQL which makes it harder/impossible to acces if you are using a remote server where you are not the admin of.

Does someone know how I can save the file in the same folder where my website is at? ( INTO OUTFILE C:\server\http\mywebsite is not acceptable )

Thanks!

Comment: this query is executing on the server you connect to, so it will be saved on it, you can select it and then save it

Comment: @user2368299 What do you mean, there is no way to do it?

Comment: @Ahmed why physical path is not acceptable? the application and the database are on different servers?

Comment: `INTO OUTFILE` always write a file on the server where MySQL is running. If you want a local file, you need to write some code to download the file from the server (through PHP) or use a program that runs on your client computer and can create a CSV file.

Comment: @eric.itzhak because I want to have an option to run my application via a hosting, where you almost never have access to the place it's saved in

Comment: @Ahmed that "almost" is the key word. save it in a path where you know you have access, something like `/home/usr/ahmed/public_html/mycoolapp/file.csv`

Answer (score 1):

this query is executing on the server you connect to, so it will be saved on it, you can select it and then save it

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM grades");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $row2[]=implode(",",$row);
    }

file_put_contents ("file.csv",implode("\r\n",$row2));
```

Comment: Yep yep it worked :) Thanks! Just changed the semicolon in line 4 to a comma which seperates it from the field

Comment: @Ahmed sorry, i forgot, really comma, not semicolon